# How can fabricjs zoom canvas background image only, not other objects' stroke?

Tags: fabricjs

I want to zoom canvas background image only, but rect stroke will scale too, I did read fabricjs docs and do not find solution for this, anyone can help me?

zoom canvas background image only, and rect stroke can not scaled.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.